# How to autofill rest of the row once a replicated value in the first column is reached

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I have an excel sheet which is defined for the customer services. I wanna use VB for row autofilling for the related value of the Column A (Customer_ID) if the value of Customer_ID repeated for the future services. So, how can I do it in the same sheet? An example of the row content is:

```
"Customer_ID"   "Identity_No."   "City"   "Customer's_Name"   "Phone_No."   "Email"

"LON9501"       "22024245423"   "London"   "John_Nash"        "9234784546"  "foobar@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Maybe a simple `VLookUP` will do: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1 Alternatively, you could also use `INDEX / MATCH`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSqcZbpoV0M

Comment: I want it added in the same sheet if there is any way.

Comment: Associate your vba code in the Change Event, and make sure the Target is in the Customer_ID column. If the new value exists in the rest of the data, and is in a new row, find the latest one that matches and fill in the rest of the row. Now it's just a matter of code. 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the following to the Change event for your worksheet ...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ARng As Range
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim iCnt As Long, iLoop As Long
    Dim found As Boolean

    Set ARng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set ARng = ARng.Cells(ARng.Rows.Count, 1)

    If Not Intersect(Target, ARng) Is Nothing Then 'Check the last cell in column A changed
        Set myRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        iCnt = myRng.Rows.Count
        found = False
        Do While Not found And iCnt > 0 'Search for another instance from the bottom up
            iCnt = iCnt - 1
            found = Target.Value = myRng.Cells(iCnt, 1).Value
            If found Then 'found another instance so populate the row
                For iLoop = 2 To myRng.Columns.Count
                    myRng.Cells(myRng.Rows.Count, iLoop) = myRng.Cells(iCnt, iLoop)
                Next iLoop
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Starting with this ...

[image]

And then typing LON9501 into cell A4 gets this ...

[image]

Comment: Great! how can I control the number of the column for filling the row?

Comment: Please spend a few minutes trying to understand how the code works. I am sure the answer will become evident. You tell me ...

Comment: Sure, Thank you very much

Comment: If this answered your question, please indicate so by clicking on the checkmark.